# Find all columns with no distinct values (unused columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on legacy SQL Server databases (2008-2012 servers), and I often find columns that are not used in any way. These columns are always NULL or all the same value. The joys of unmaintained legacy code...

How can I check all columns in a table and return those that have no meaningful data?

I know how to use `DISTINCT` and such, but just not how to gather all columns with no distinct values.

Comment: As a side note, *both* SQL Server *and* SQL Server 2008 are **completely** out of support. You really need to implement your upgrade plans from 4+ and 1+ years ago on those respective servers

Comment: `count(col) = count(*) or count(col) = 0`. But what are you going to do with the found "no meaningful data" columns? I'd say don't touch them, because if you do, something will quit working. Maybe not today, but perhaps January 2nd.

Comment: Just because a column has the same value throughout doesn't mean it isn't used, either. I'm aware of a several columns in environments I use where the a column only has a single value, as it's for future-proofing for a scenario that we *expect* to come up in the future, or is for a feature that isn't used in that environment but is in another. For the latter removing the column from that environment would be a (significant) breaking change, as the code for the environments is intentionally the same as the environments should also be *the same*.

Comment: The real question is, why are you looking for columns that aren't used?

Comment: @ThomA Indeed very out of support, this question is part of updating a legacy system, as this hasn't been maintained for a very long time. I'm not the one who decides on the priorities, unfortunately.

@ everyone, I want to find which columns aren't used across all our environments and mark them as irrelevant on paper. The previous devs really liked creating new columns, and now I need to reverse engineer whether they are used for anything whenever I want to make a translation to the new system. It is just costing me a whole lot of time to check everything and I want to cut down on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm a "glutten" for punishment, this is a SQL Server 2008 "friendly" method to achieve this. It builds a *massive* dynamic statement for *every* table and column in your database, and then does a `COUNT(DISTINCT <Column Name>)` against *every column*. Note that if you have any deprecated data types, this will fail (I suggest omitted those if you do, but then things like `image` have been deprecated since 2005 so you wouldn't be using that any more, right? *Right?*).

Don't expect this to be quick, it won't be. Doing a distinct count on every every row, on every column, on every table, will take *a long time* with anything but a tiny database.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #ColumnCounts (SchemaName sysname,
                            TableName sysname,
                            ColumnName sysname,
                            DistinctCount int,
                            INDEX IX_DistinctCount (DistinctCount) INCLUDE (SchemaName,TableName, ColumnName));

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

WITH ColumnSQL AS(
    SELECT t.object_id,
           STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(N',',@CRLF,N'             COUNT(DISTINCT ', QUOTENAME(c.name),N') AS ', QUOTENAME(c.name))
                  FROM sys.columns c
                  WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value(N'(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,16,N'') AS ColumnCounts,
           STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(N',',@CRLF,N'        (N',QUOTENAME(c.name,''''),N',T.', QUOTENAME(c.name),N')')
                  FROM sys.columns c
                  WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value(N'(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') AS ColumnUnpivot
    FROM sys.tables t)
SELECT @SQL =  (SELECT @CRLF +
                       N'INSERT INTO #ColumnCounts (SChemaName, TableName, ColumnName, DistinctCount)' + @CRLF +
                       N'SELECT T.SchemaName,' + @CRLF +
                       N'       T.TableName,' + @CRLF +
                       N'       V.ColumnName,' + @CRLF +
                       N'       V.ColumnDistinctCount' + @CRLF +
                       N'FROM (SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(s.name, '''') + N' AS SchemaName,' + @CRLF +
                       N'             N' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') +  N' AS TableName,' + @CRLF +
                       N'             ' + C.ColumnCounts + @CRLF +
                       N'      FROM '+ QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N') T' + @CRLF +
                       N'      CROSS APPLY(VALUES' + C.ColumnUnpivot + N')V(ColumnName,ColumnDistinctCount)'
                FROM sys.schemas s  
                     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                     JOIN ColumnSQL C ON t.object_id = C.object_id
                FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)');

--SELECT @SQL;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

SELECT *
FROM #ColumnCounts
WHERE DistinctCount IN (0,1);

DROP TABLE #ColumnCounts;
```

Comment: Holy moly! That is one hell of a query. SSMS did complain about the include statement in line 5, but once I changed that I ran.
Well, "ran". Remember those deprecated types? We have a lot of `text` columns... Yes, I know... I'm lucky that I want it to be my job to fix unmaintained systems

Comment: @Joppiedoppie, the `INCLUDE` is fine, for some reason SSMS' intellisense doesn't recognise the syntax, but it is supported.

Comment: If you *do* have `text` columns, @Joppiedoppie, then  the above is going to error; you'll need to exclude those from the datasets in the CTE. You cannot perform aggregate functions on deprecated data types.

Comment: weird, SSMS doesn't want to run it: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '('.`. Possibly an outdated or too-much-updated SSMS?

Comment: That's a SQL Server error, not an SSMS error, @Joppiedoppie . Maybe the syntax wasn't supported in 2008. It was in 2012+ (but even in SQL Server 2022 with SSMS 19.3 Intellisense complains about the syntax even though it's valid). /shrug

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I modified line 5 to just be `INDEX IX_DistinctCount (DistinctCount));` (I believe you when you say it should work, but now it executes). I also added `and system_type_id not in (34,35)` to the `where` clauses on line 15 and 19, and now it executes. 4939 rows, just for one outdated test db, for just one customer, 49 seconds. Absolutely wonderful query you've made, many thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest creating the index outside of the table `CREATE` with the `INCLUDE`, @Joppiedoppie . The index will be pointless without the `INCLUDE`.